# View /folder/index.php when user goes to /folder

Tags: php, redirect, web

I'm not sure if php already does it by default, but, I want my users to see the page `www.domain.com/folder/index.php` when they go to `www.domain.com/folder` and instead see `www.domain.com/folder` itself in the address bar. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is opening any page of name index in it. And it does not shows the page name `www.domain.com/folder/index.php` it will only show `www.domain.com/folder`.

Comment: I have `www.domain.com/index.php` and `www.domain.com/folder/index.php` as two different files, is it still ok?

Comment: @AyushKhemka yeah its ok because it is two different folder. If you just navigate `www.domain.com` it will open `index.php` of `www.domain.com/index.php`.